# Is it possible to get the position of div within the browser viewport? Not within the document. Within the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is this doable in either IE7 or Firefox?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can do it in both - get the position relative to the document, then subtract the scroll position.

```
var e = document.getElementById('xxx');
var offset = {x:0,y:0};
while (e)
{
    offset.x += e.offsetLeft;
    offset.y += e.offsetTop;
    e = e.offsetParent;
}

if (document.documentElement && (document.documentElement.scrollTop || document.documentElement.scrollLeft))
{
    offset.x -= document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
    offset.y -= document.documentElement.scrollTop;
}
else if (document.body && (document.body.scrollTop || document.body.scrollLeft))
{
    offset.x -= document.body.scrollLeft;
    offset.y -= document.body.scrollTop;
}
else if (window.pageXOffset || window.pageYOffset)
{
    offset.x -= window.pageXOffset;
    offset.y -= window.pageYOffset;
}

alert(offset.x + '\n' + offset.y);
```

Comment: Please replace `position` with `offset` and `bodt` with `body`.

Comment: hats-off... whoever wrote this.

Comment: This is a great answer, but one important note that might not have been relevant at the time of this answer:
In browsers with "elastic scroll" like Chrome/Mac, the scrollTop can be negative (you can scroll past the page boundary and it will "bounce back"). If you're absolutely positioning elements based on this algorithm, you might need to account for this behavior, including out-of-bounds scroll offsets.

Answer (score 12):

[Pasting from the answer I gave [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350581/how-to-get-an-elements-top-position-relative-to-the-browsers-window/18794913#18794913)]

The native `getBoundingClientRect()` method has been around for quite a while now, and does exactly what the question asks for. Plus it is supported across all browsers (including IE 5, it seems!)

From [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) MDN page:

*The returned value is a TextRectangle object, which contains read-only left, top, right and bottom properties describing the border-box, in pixels, with the top-left **relative to the top-left of the viewport**.*

You use it like so:

```
var viewportOffset = el.getBoundingClientRect();
// these are relative to the viewport, i.e. the window
var top = viewportOffset.top;
var left = viewportOffset.left;
```

Answer (score 4):

Try [the dimensions jQuery plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/dimensions).  See [this demo](http://brandonaaron.net/docs/dimensions/#sample-4).

```
$('#myelement.').offset();
```

Answer (score 3):

In IE and Firefox 3, you can use [getBoundingClientRect](http://ejohn.org/blog/getboundingclientrect-is-awesome) for this; no framework necessary.

But, yes, you should use a framework if you need to support other browsers as well.

Answer (score 0):

You could subtract the div's offsetTop from the document.body.scrollTop

This seems to work on IE7 and FF3, but on a very simple page. I haven't checked with nested DIVs.

Comment: No, the offsetTop only shows your position inside the parent div. This works for the top-level div and fails with others. Note how the first answer walks up through parents accumulating offsets.

Answer (score 0):

Using Prototype it would be:

```
$('divname').viewportOffset.top
$('divname').viewportOffset.left
```