# How to get an element's top position relative to the browser's viewport?

Tags: javascript

I want to get the position of an element relative to the browser's viewport (the viewport in which the page is displayed, not the whole page). How can this be done in JavaScript?

Many thanks

Comment: I think this question is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/211703/is-it-possible-to-get-the-position-of-div-within-the-browser-viewport-not-withi which has a really nice solution.

Comment: @JakobRunge, That was "nice" in 2013?

Comment: Consider accepting a solution.

Answer (score 417):

The existing answers are now outdated. The native `getBoundingClientRect()` method has been around for quite a while now, and does exactly what the question asks for. Plus it is supported across all browsers (including IE 5, it seems!)

From [MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect):

*The returned value is a TextRectangle object, which contains read-only left, top, right and bottom properties describing the border-box, in pixels, with the top-left **relative to the top-left of the viewport**.*

You use it like so:

```
var viewportOffset = el.getBoundingClientRect();
// these are relative to the viewport, i.e. the window
var top = viewportOffset.top;
var left = viewportOffset.left;
```

Comment: This may not work correctly when use browser zoom (Android Chrome). Solution from @rism ([see below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1350681/2757230))works in this case

Comment: Good for most cases, but it assumes the element is not inside an embedded iframe, right? The question is asking about relative the browser's window. The el.getBoundingClientRect() will return relative the iframe's window, not the browser window.

Comment: The question is asking about relative the browser's window.

Comment: @Denilson `getBoundingClientRect().top` is not in my IE11 it returns 0. Have you any solution.

Comment: @Arif: Sorry, but I cannot reproduce your issue. I tested this on IE11 and still got results: https://codepen.io/denilsonsa/pen/ypqyXj

Comment: You simplify it a bit with `const { top, left } = viewportOffset`

Answer (score 113):

On my case, just to be safe regarding scrolling, I added the window.scroll to the equation:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myElement');
var topPos = element.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.scrollY;
var leftPos = element.getBoundingClientRect().left + window.scrollX;
```

That allows me to get the real relative position of element on document, even if it has been scrolled.

Comment: Aren't you supposed to add the scroll position instead of subtracting it?

Comment: @Fabio `getBoundingClientRect().top` is not in my IE11 it returns 0. Have you any solution.

Comment: @Arif `window.scrollY || window.pageYOffset` may improve support

Comment: I agree, there is better cross-browser compatibility for pageYOffset .

Answer (score 25):

```
var element =  document.querySelector('selector');
var bodyRect = document.body.getBoundingClientRect(),
    elemRect = element.getBoundingClientRect(),
    offset   = elemRect.top - bodyRect.top;
```

Comment: This seems to calculate from the top of the document, not the viewport

Answer (score 19):

**Edit:**  Add some code to account for the page scrolling.

```
function findPos(id) {
    var node = document.getElementById(id);     
    var curtop = 0;
    var curtopscroll = 0;
    if (node.offsetParent) {
        do {
            curtop += node.offsetTop;
            curtopscroll += node.offsetParent ? node.offsetParent.scrollTop : 0;
        } while (node = node.offsetParent);

        alert(curtop - curtopscroll);
    }
}
```

The id argument is the id of the element whose offset you want. Adapted from a [quirksmode post](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/findpos.html).

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I think you misunderstood my question, I know how to get the top of an element relative to the page, what I'm trying to do is get the position relative to the 'viewport'(ie. the browser window, not the document)

Comment: Sorry, your use of 'viewport' threw me. So, you're saying you want to account for the browser chrome, ie bookmarks toolbar, location bar, etc?

Comment: No, just the window through which you see the page. If the page is scrolled this will be different than the document top, otherwise they are the same.

Comment: Oh OK, I understand. Not sure how to do that...will edit my answer if I come up with something.

Comment: I made the code above a little uglier but it works...use offsetParent.scrollTop

Comment: Thanks a lot. I see prototype uses parentNode instead of offsetParent for getting the scrollTop but I don't know the reason.

Answer (score 13):

jQuery implements this quite elegantly. If you look at the source for jQuery's `offset`, you'll find this is basically how it's implemented:

```
var rect = elem.getBoundingClientRect();
var win = elem.ownerDocument.defaultView;

return {
    top: rect.top + win.pageYOffset,
    left: rect.left + win.pageXOffset
};
```

Answer (score 9):

```
function inViewport(element) {
    let bounds = element.getBoundingClientRect();
    let viewWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    let viewHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    if (bounds['left'] < 0) return false;
    if (bounds['top'] < 0) return false;
    if (bounds['right'] > viewWidth) return false;
    if (bounds['bottom'] > viewHeight) return false;

    return true;
}
```

[source](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-test-if-an-element-is-in-the-viewport-with-vanilla-javascript/)

Answer (score 5):

The function on [this](http://blog.jpencola.com/2009/08/17/getting-coordinates-relative-to-the-viewport-in-javascript/) page will return a rectangle with the top, left, height and width co ordinates of a passed element relative to the browser view port.

```
    localToGlobal: function( _el ) {
       var target = _el,
       target_width = target.offsetWidth,
       target_height = target.offsetHeight,
       target_left = target.offsetLeft,
       target_top = target.offsetTop,
       gleft = 0,
       gtop = 0,
       rect = {};

       var moonwalk = function( _parent ) {
        if (!!_parent) {
            gleft += _parent.offsetLeft;
            gtop += _parent.offsetTop;
            moonwalk( _parent.offsetParent );
        } else {
            return rect = {
            top: target.offsetTop + gtop,
            left: target.offsetLeft + gleft,
            bottom: (target.offsetTop + gtop) + target_height,
            right: (target.offsetLeft + gleft) + target_width
            };
        }
    };
        moonwalk( target.offsetParent );
        return rect;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can try:

`node.offsetTop - window.scrollY`

It works on Opera with viewport meta tag defined.

Comment: If I understand [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetTop) correctly, `offsetTop` is relative to the closest positioned element. Which, depending on the page structure, may or may not be root element.

Answer (score 3):

I am assuming an element having an id of `btn1` exists in the web page, and also that jQuery is included. This has worked across all modern browsers of Chrome, FireFox, IE >=9 and Edge.
jQuery is only being used to determine the position relative to document.

```
var screenRelativeTop =  $("#btn1").offset().top - (window.scrollY || 
                                            window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop);

var screenRelativeLeft =  $("#btn1").offset().left - (window.scrollX ||
                                           window.pageXOffset || document.body.scrollLeft);
```

Comment: jQuery is JavaScript. I believe you meant _"it's not 100% vanilla/pure JS."_

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers. It seems Prototype already has a function that does this (the page() function). By viewing the source code of the function, I found that it first calculates the element offset position relative to the page (i.e. the document top), then subtracts the scrollTop from that. See the source code of prototype for more details.

Comment: Good decision. It's probably best to go with one of the major libraries as they're more likely to give the same result across browsers. If you're curious, check my my answer. The code there will do this but I have no idea how it will hold up across browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes `getBoundingClientRect()` object's property value shows 0 for IE. In that case you have to set `display = 'block'` for the element. You can use below code for all browser to get offset.

Extend jQuery functionality :

```
(function($) {
    jQuery.fn.weOffset = function () {
        var de = document.documentElement;
        $(this).css("display", "block");
        var box = $(this).get(0).getBoundingClientRect();
        var top = box.top + window.pageYOffset - de.clientTop;
        var left = box.left + window.pageXOffset - de.clientLeft;
        return { top: top, left: left };
    };
}(jQuery));
```

Use :

```
var elementOffset = $("#" + elementId).weOffset();
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on Derek's answer.

```
/**
 * Gets element's x position relative to the visible viewport.
 */
function getAbsoluteOffsetLeft(el) {
  let offset = 0;
  let currentElement = el;

  while (currentElement !== null) {
    offset += currentElement.offsetLeft;
    offset -= currentElement.scrollLeft;
    currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent;
  }

  return offset;
}

/**
 * Gets element's y position relative to the visible viewport.
 */
function getAbsoluteOffsetTop(el) {
  let offset = 0;
  let currentElement = el;

  while (currentElement !== null) {
    offset += currentElement.offsetTop;
    offset -= currentElement.scrollTop;
    currentElement = currentElement.offsetParent;
  }

  return offset;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something for Angular2 +. Tested on version 13

```js
event.srcElement.getBoundingClientRect().top;
```

Comment: What if the element has transform translate or some of its parents, getBoundingClienRect() won't take that in consideration, any idea?