# How to prevent an element from ever sticking out of screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Say there are some "absolutely positioned" elements whose coordinates(unit: %) are grabbed with Ajax.

Sometimes a certain edge of them sticks out of the screen, like when they are too right or too top. I cannot position them as `right: 0` because their parent element is already "absolutely positioned", hence that won't work.

**How can one prevent an element from ever sticking out of screen, given its direct parent element is not the `document.body`?**

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css` at Question?,  create stacksnippets to demonstrate?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the css property `overflow: hidden` on the `body`? For example:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #222;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/450x150" alt="" />
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae suscipit, autem magnam ab. Possimus perferendis officiis doloremque impedit quia quos labore optio quas cum incidunt. Blanditiis dicta, sunt numquam quos.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Recusandae suscipit, autem magnam ab. Possimus perferendis officiis doloremque impedit quia quos labore optio quas cum incidunt. Blanditiis dicta, sunt numquam quos.</p>
</div>
```

If you want content to never move *out of range* of the body, you'd need to grab that element's position relative to the window and not allow it to move beyond its borders (for example, any given element's `left` position relative to the body shall never be more than `windowWidth-currentElementWidth`). You can find more on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350581/how-to-get-an-elements-top-position-relative-to-the-browsers-window)

Comment: Yet knowing the element's left position relative to body is one thing, force it to not move beyond the body is another thing. I can get `element.getBoundingClientRect().left` but I cannot set it, because it's readonly. Setting `element.style.left` won't work because its parent element is also `position: absolute`.