# Why can't I use getBoundingClientRect()?

Tags: html, typescript, protractor

I am trying to write a protractor test to check that a page's footer is at the bottom of the page.

I've looked at sources like these to help me:

[How to get an element's top position relative to the browser's viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1350581/how-to-get-an-elements-top-position-relative-to-the-browsers-viewport)
https://plainjs.com/javascript/styles/get-the-position-of-an-element-relative-to-the-document-24/

I want to use the getBoundingClientRect function discussed in these sources to get the footer's position, but I am getting an error saying: `footer.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

Here is the relevant portion of my code:

```
footer = element(by.css('lib-footer > mat-toolbar'));
const viewportOffset = footer.getBoundingClientRect();
const bottom = viewportOffset.bottom;

browser.driver.manage().window().getSize().then((size) => {
    expect(bottom).toBeGreaterThan(size.height - 50);
});
```

I know that the footer element is defined because I have already run other tests on it to check things like its color and size.

**Why am I being told that getBoundingClientRect is not a function?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurred because you are trying to call the `getBoundingClientRect()` function on the `ElementFinder` type, but the `ElementFinder` does not have and can not call the `getBoundingClientRect` function.

The `getBoundingClientRect` function could be called from the `Element` object, it is the most general base class from which all objects in a `Document` inherit. It only has methods and properties common to all kinds of elements. More specific classes inherit from Element.

So in your case, you should use the `executeScript` to execute JavaScript in the context of the currently selected frame or window.

**SOLUTION:**

```
// Promise based

const footer = $('lib-footer > mat-toolbar'); // or element(by.css(''));
let viewportOffset = '';
browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect()', footer).then(value => {
 viewportOffset = value;
});
const bottom = viewportOffset.bottom;

browser.driver.manage().window().getSize().then((size) => {
  expect(bottom).toBeGreaterThan(size.height - 50);
});


// async/await - Highly recommended. Don't forget to add `async` before the function to use `await`


const footer = $('lib-footer > mat-toolbar');
const viewportOffset = await browser.executeScript('return arguments[0].getBoundingClientRect()', footer);
const bottom = viewportOffset.bottom;
const windowSize = await browser.driver.manage().window().getSize();

expect(bottom).toBeGreaterThan(windowSize.height - 50);
```

Comment: This is great!! I'm just wondering.  If my window height is 900 and the footer is at the bottom of the window, why is bottom being set to a value of 768?

Comment: because the screen resolution and browser window size are not necessarily equal. The display resolution or display modes of a digital television, computer monitor or display device is the number of distinct pixels in each dimension that can be displayed ... "1024 × 768" means the width is 1024 pixels and the height is 768 pixels. While getSize() is returning the actual browser size. Try to maximize the window size `browser.driver.manage().window().maximize();`

Comment: The browser window size is set to 1600 x 900 pixels. The screen resolution is larger than that, so shouldn't 'bottom' be very close to 900 if it's at the very bottom of the browser?.