# THREE.JS Stop animate() function when parent IFRAME is offscreen

Tags: html, animation, three.js, parent, requestanimationframe

I have Bootstrap one-page template with a THREE.js scene in the middle as the background. Let's say its parent `iframe` has `id="3D"`. The task is to 
skip `animate()` / `render()` functions while the `iframe` is offscreen.

See attached wireframe:

[image: wireframe]

I didn't find any clear solution on how to do this. Maybe something connected to the scrolling (mousewheel) event or maybe a method how to check if `iframe` is onscreen or not? The code should be inside THREE.js script if it's possible.

That's why a solution like http://jsfiddle.net/t2L274ty doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a way to check div position on screen based on scroll position:
[Is it possible to get the position of div within the browser viewport? Not within the document. Within the window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/211703/is-it-possible-to-get-the-position-of-div-within-the-browser-viewport-not-withi)

Test it out and see what Y values you'll get. Then you can call scene.render only when Y is in certain range. Don't break/return out of the animation loop when Y is out of range since it's recursive and won't resume if user scrolls the scene back in view.

Comment: sorry, it's <iframe> not <div>

Comment: @VVK Okay, this should work for `iframe` as well. Did you try it?